# UITableView cell not resizing its frame to IPhone 6s size on initial load

Tags: ios, uitableview

As I'm using UITableView and the custom cell inside tableview setting its width to 320 in IPhone 5,IPhone 5s and IPhone 4 and less but in IPhone 6 and 6P it is not resizing tableview cell width to 414 on initial load even i'm calling tableview reloadData in viewDidLoad too.I know tableview use default value of its size on inital load but I want its initial width to be 414 on Iphone 6 & Ipone 6P...

As I'm using custom cell too..and its width is also 320 in Iphone 6 & Ipone 6P I know it is becoz of tableview...

I had called all layout methods but no luck...Can Someone resolve this of my mine and put some light on this topic...

I had done..

```
cell.bounds = [UIScreen mainscreen].bounds;
```

in cellforrowatindexpath but i think this is not precise solution but it is working fine...

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using auto layout? If yes, then please share constraints you have applied on TableView.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

**Autolayout is always easy and good** but if you want programmatically

You should get the screen size (width) at run time and then update the table view frame

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, set_new_width_here, tableView.contentSize.height)

        //or

        var tableFrame: CGRect = tableView.frame
        tableFrame.size.width = set_new_wdith_here
        tableListView.frame = tableFrame
    }
```

PS: if you absolute beginner with auto-layout I would suggest please try to reset auto-layout constraints it works almost every time i use.

[image]

Comment: Thnxx for reply but the problem is with custom cell inside tableview not  with tableview

Answer (score 0):

Please use AutoLayout on tableView and give Leading,Trailing,Top and Bottom Constraints to tableView with its SuperView,So tableView's frame will be according to its SuperView in all devices.

Comment: I had already done thiss..Thnxx for reply...but its not resizing in iphone 6 and 6 plus on initial load then its resizing

Comment: Would you please just let  me know the Hierarchy?

Comment: tableView is inside ViewController's main View or any custom view?

Comment: See my updated question...As tableview is returning right frame but not its cell

Comment: cell always take width from tableView accordingly.please share screen shot of iPhone6 issue.

Comment: See the hierarchy...In updated question as cell is not taking width from tableview in initial load in iphone 6

Comment: I can see a view inside cell whose name is cardView,have you applied constraints on that view?

Comment: YEs I had applied ..I'm talking about custom cell width not subviews of custom cell

Comment: Please select cell and once ensure that Use Auto Layout and Use Size Classes is enable to Yes in File Inspector.